# Fibonacci numbers as infinite sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, fibonacci-numbers

I was going through papers such as [this](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/29-2/klein.pdf) one and [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X03003317) one, hoping to find an explicit formula for the $n$-th Fibonacci numbers as an infinite sum. I could not find any. Surely, there are quite a few interesting infinite sums with $F_n$ in the summand, and finite-sum representations of $F_n$, but

> I am interested in 'combinatorial' (interpret this qualifier as broadly as you please) functions $f(a,b)$ with
>   $$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(n,k) = F_n$$
>   Where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

*Obligatory vague catch-all: no trivial solutions!*

Comment: so clearly not the soft diagonals of pascals triangle.

Comment: What makes you think there _is_ a representation by infinite sums?

Comment: Your specifications appear to me to be skirting the borders of inconsistency.  If I can interpret "combinatorial" as broadly as I please, then I can take it to include such formulas as
$$
f(n,k)=\left(\frac{F_n}{1+F_n}\right)^k\ .
$$
But I would also regard that as being a "trivial" solution.

Comment: @Ionza Ieggiera yes, I would consider any solutions defined using the Fibonacci numbers to be trivial.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: actually there is one (at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to represent the Fibonacci numbers through infinite sums may be obtained 
by considering the very interesting family of functions that are called *Generalized Binomial Series*
in the renowned "Concrete Mathematics"(1) treatise.

Please refer thereto for a wide general analysis while here I will summarize without demonstration
some properties of interest to our particular aim.

The Generalized Binomial Series is defined as
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\cal B}_{\,t} (z)\quad \left| {\;t \in \mathbb R} \right.\quad
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{\left( {t\,k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k - 1\,} } } \over {k!}}z^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{1 \over {\left( {tk - k + 1} \right)}}\binom{  t\,k }{   k } z^{\,k} }
  = 1 + z\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{1 \over {k + 1}}\binom{  t\,k + t }{   k } z^{\,k} }  \cr} 
$$
and it comes that its powers also have a simple representation
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\cal B}_{\,t} (z)^{\,r} \quad \left| {\;t,r \in \mathbb R} \right.\quad
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{r \over {t\,k + r}}\binom{  t\,k + r }{   k } z^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{r\left( {t\,k + r - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k - 1\,} } } \over {k!}}z^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 + rz\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{1\over {k + 1}}\binom{  \,t\,k + t + r - 1 }{   k }  z^{\,k} }  \cr} 
$$

Now we have that for $t=1/2, \, r= 1/2$ 
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\cal B}_{\,\,1/2} (z)^{\,\,1/2}  = {{z + \sqrt {z^{\,2}  + 4} } \over 2} = \exp \left( {{\rm arcsinh}\left( {{z \over 2}} \right)} \right)  \cr 
  &  - {\cal B}_{\,\,1/2} ( - z)^{\,\,1/2}  =  - {\cal B}_{\,\,1/2} (z)^{\,\, - \,1/2}  = {{z - \sqrt {z^{\,2}  + 4} } \over 2} =  - \exp \left( { - \,{\rm arcsinh}\left( {{z \over 2}} \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$

Therefore
$$
\eqalign{
  & F_{\,n} \quad \left| {\;n \in \,Z\;} \right.\quad  = {{\varphi ^{\,\;n}  - \hat \varphi ^{\,\;n} } \over {\sqrt 5 }} =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}\left( {{\cal B}_{\,\,1/2} (1)^{\,\,n/2}  - \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} {\cal B}_{\,\,1/2} ( - 1)^{\,\,n/2} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}\left( {1 + {n \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
  {{1 \over {k + 1}}\left( \matrix{  \left( {k + n - 1} \right)/2 \cr   k \cr}  \right)}
  - \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \left( {1 - {n \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)^k } \over {k + 1}}\left( \matrix{  \left( {k + n - 1} \right)/2 \cr   k \cr}  \right)} } \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}\left( {\left( {1 - \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} } \right) + {n \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
 {{{1 + \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n + k} } \over {k + 1}}\left( \matrix{  \left( {k + n - 1} \right)/2 \cr  k \cr}  \right)} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}\left( {2\bmod (n,2) + {n \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
 {{{2\left[ {k \equiv n\;\left( {\bmod 2} \right)} \right]} \over {k + 1}}\left( \matrix{  \left( {k + n - 1} \right)/2 \cr  k \cr}  \right)} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}\left( {2\bmod (n,2) + n\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}
 {{1 \over {2j + \bmod (n,2) + 1}}\left( \matrix{  \left( {2j + \bmod (n,2) + n - 1} \right)/2 \cr   2j + \bmod (n,2) \cr}  \right)} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}\left( {2\bmod (n,2) + n\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}
 {{1 \over {2j + \bmod (n,2) + 1}}\left( \matrix{   j + \left\lceil {n/2} \right\rceil  - 1/2 \cr   2j + \bmod (n,2) \cr}  \right)} } \right) \cr} 
$$
where the square brackets denote the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

For instance, for $n=10$ the first partial sums from the expression above give
$$F_{10} = 55 :  4.47213595, 22.91969677, 43.9037972, 53.27169917, 54.93059848, 55.00223277, 54.999822, 55.00002003, 54.99999728, 55.00000042, 54.99999993$$

(1)"Concrete Mathematics: a foundation for computer science" R. L. Graham - D.E. Knuth - O. Patshnik - Addison-Wesley 2nd Ed. 1994